Ubuntu Mate, bluetooth mouse
I have two bluetooth mice,both working fine with Windows. Both will connect with Ubuntu and even give signal strength and battery power, but no mouse movement. I suspect the laptop is treating the mouse as something else, not a pointing device. How do I access the bluetooth settings (terminal?) to check the device settings?

Run bluetoothctl devices to list all connected Bluetooth devices. Then run bluetoothctl info <device-mac-address> to retrieve detailed information about the device, including its type. Replace <device-mac-address> with the MAC address of your Bluetooth mouse.
The Class field in the output indicates the device type. For a mouse, you should see something like Class: 0x000580 where 0x000580 corresponds to a Bluetooth pointing device such as a mouse. In 0x000580, 0x05 refers to the peripheral device category and 0x80 indicates a pointing device such as a mouse.
The Alias field in the output shows the device model.
